# Error when building Qt5.13.2 from source on Windows for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, build, static

I have a problem while trying to build **Qt 5.13.2** from source for **Android**.
I have used **PowerShell** on Windows 10.
Before configure command I have set **JDK_ROOT** path:

```
set "JDK_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin
```

This configure command is executed successfully:

```
..\src\qt5\configure -prefix E:\Qt\Static\Qt5.13.2Android -platform win32-g++ -opengl es2 -xplatform android-clang -android-sdk C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk -android-ndk C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147 -nomake tests -nomake examples -opensource -confirm-license
```

After this I execute:

```
mingw32-make -j4
```

and shortly after start the build stops with this output at the end:

```
del ..\..\..\lib\libQt5Bootstrap.a 2>NUL
ar -rc ..\..\..\lib\libQt5Bootstrap.a @object_script.libQt5Bootstrap.Release
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'E:/Qt/Static/build-android/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap'
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'E:/Qt/Static/build-android/qtbase/src/tools/bootstrap'
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'E:/Qt/Static/build-android/qtbase/src'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:51: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/Qt/Static/build-android/qtbase'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:87: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

Any suggestion or idea why build stops? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Same happens with Qt 5.14.2 and Qt 5.12.5

Comment: I feel like the actual error message is missing from your output. Using `-j4` is helpful to speed up a build, but it really muddles the output as each process tries to write to the console at the same time. Try removing the `-j4` so it all builds sequentially. Then you should be able to see what the real error is.

Comment: @JarMan thank you very much for your reply. I was wondering why there is no error. I will try as you suggested and post updated as soon as possible. Thanks again.

Comment: @JarMan that is actually the solution.Without -j4 i built the qt successfully. Please delete your comment and post it in answer so I can mark it as solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) for `make` says that the`-j` option tells it to divide up the work into multiple "jobs" that run in parallel. That is helpful because it completes faster that way. But the output becomes more confusing as each job writes to the same console and you can't easily tell which output comes from which job. So when you get a compile error, it's often hard to find what the error message actually is. So when I get an error, I usually remove the `-j` option so that the output stays sequential and I can actually read it.

**Note:** You wrote in the comments that simply removing this option allowed qt to compile successfully, so that's why I'm writing this as an answer. But I really don't know why that would help. Maybe there's something that was getting compiled out of order with the multiple jobs. Anyway, I'm glad this answer helped you.

Comment: yes I agree with Note. If I find what exactly was problem, I would post update in the comments.